# An nlobjSearchFilter contains an invalid operator, or is not in proper syntax: internalid. Error while using record.submitFields

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have tried passing various values to id. Whenever a wrong internalid is passed I am getting a "That record does not exist." but when a valid internal id is passed the script throws "An nlobjSearchFilter contains an invalid operator, or is not in proper syntax: internalid."

```
 var recordID = record.submitFields({
  "type": record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
  "id":9837,
  "values": {
    "memo": "MEMOTXT"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing wrong with the code that you’ve shown.  It’s likely that this error is caused by another script on the sales order record that isn’t expecting an `XEDIT` event, which is what `record.submitFields()` will trigger.

During an `XEDIT` event, user event scripts only have access to some basic fields about the record and the fields that were submitted.  They don’t have access to every field on the record.

If the other script isn’t expecting this scenario, they may be trying to perform an action, but some expected values are null because they’re not available to the user event script.

Comment: IMO This is the most likely scenario. You may be able find the culprit by searching script logs under saved searches - new

Answer (score 0):

The record.submitFields method has an optional parameter named "enablesourcing".  Try running it with it as false.

```
var recordID = record.submitFields({
  type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
  id: 9837,
  values: {
    memo: 'MEMOTXT'
  },
  options: {
    enableSourcing: false, //default is true
    ignoreMandatoryFields : true //default is false
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, there is a User Event on Salesorder that you need to track down, period